# Elastic search query to get the latest child document based on the parent id

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

In the below data, there are

- Two-parent content Id's (Content_1 & Content_2)
- Three Child Article doc (Article_1, Article_2, Article_3) for Content_1
- Three Child Gallery doc (Gallery_1, Gallery_2, Gallery_3) for Content_2

Data:

```
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-04T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Article_3",
    "ContentId": "Content_1"
},
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-03T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Article_2",
    "ContentId": "Content_1"
},
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-02T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Article_1",
    "ContentId": "Content_1"
}


"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "null",
    "Id": "Gallery_3",
    "ContentId": "Content_2"
},
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-03T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Gallery_2",
    "ContentId": "Content_2"
},
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-02T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Gallery_1",
    "ContentId": "Content_2"
}
```

Could someone please help me with a query to fetch the result as below when "Content_1" & "Content_2" is passed as the input parameters.

Expected Result to be:

```
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-04T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Article_3",
    "ContentId": "Content_1"
}
"doc":{
    "PublishedDate": "2018-07-03T03:00:00Z",
    "Id": "Gallery_2",
    "ContentId": "Content_2"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You can use [sorting on `PublishedDate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Aggregate by contentID.
Then retrieve the last event using a top_hits.

Should be something like :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ContentId",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "last_event": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "PublishedDate": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried it but it returns only one content (Content_1) and not Content_2. I think it is very close and I'm missing something simple.

Comment: yes, my bad, just change the size in the first agg (i edited to 10). You boviously have to have a querry part if you want only target some contentid and not all of them.

Comment: Great, that worked mate. Thanks. But in future, if I got 20 content, will it return only 10? Is there a way not to restrict the number of content returned?

Comment: "size": 10 will limit the number of content returned by the first aggregation (change the value). Content with the more orrurance will be returned. 

If you want to target only  1 or 2 content, you have to make a querry before., ex:

{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "ContentId" : ["Content_1", "Content_2"]
    }
  },
"aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {....